# Worksheet Audit Log Part 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a script which provides me with an Audit Log of changes made on my Data Tab (I would like to provide the user access to make one off changes and therefore don't want to completely lock and protect the tab).

When the user selects 1 cell this works perfectly fine, however, when the user goes to select multiple cells and attempts to delete them or change them the script crashes.

What line of code is required to either, not allow the user to select more than one cell, or if they do then produce a popup mentioning they can only select 1 cell.

````
Dim PreVal

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'This sets our previous value once we have selected the cell value to change
    PreVal = Target.Value
End Sub
    
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastRow
    
    'If we change the cell we selected then the worksheet change event is triggered
    If Target.Value <> PreVal Then
    
        LastRow = Worksheets("Logged Changes").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'If the new value of the cell is not the same a previous value then logging of details begins
        Worksheets("Logged Changes").Cells(LastRow, 2).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
        Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreVal & " to " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch this by checking the `Selection.Count` result.

Something like this in it's simplest form:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Checks for the count of selected cells and only assigns PreVal if = 1
    If Not Selection.Count > 1 Then
        PreVal = Target.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "You can only select 1 cell at a time.", VbCritical + VbOkOnly, "To Many Cells Selected!"
    End If
End Sub
```

You could also write it using `Target.Count` instead of `Selection.Count`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Checks for the count of selected cells and only assigns PreVal if = 1
    If Not Target.Count > 1 Then
        PreVal = Target.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "You can only select 1 cell at a time.", VbCritical + VbOkOnly, "To Many Cells Selected!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This will only assign `PreVal = Target.Value` if the count of selected cells is not greater than 1 (and considering the function won't fire if nothing is selected, it will only work when 1 cell is selected).

There are a few ways to achieve preventing errors occuring with multi-cell selections, some things that come to mind are;

- Throw the message as above but add another global variable, e.g. `CellCount` and then check in your `Worksheet_Change` event - `If CellCount > 1 Then Exit Sub` to prevent the code running.
- Protect the worksheet and programmatically unprotect, apply changes and reprotect. Incorporate some checking like the point above to dictate when this code runs so that way  if conditions aren't met the cell is locked.
- Force selection to a different cell altogether so if multi-cells are selected the user doesn't have a chance to make any edits based on that range (with warnings to only select 1 cell etc.)
- Resize the `Target` range using `Set Target = Me.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))` which will change the `Target.Address` to the top left cell of the selected cells. This alone won't move or change the actuall selection on sheet but could be used to advise the user this cell will be used in place of the multi-cells selected etc.

Comment: Thanks!! This is very helpful, i have gone for a hybrid option because i'd like to restrict the user of being able to delete more than 1 cell in one go. Let me know your thoughts on the below 


```Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox ("Please select 1 cell only")
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
Exit Sub

Else
    'This sets our previous value once we have selected the cell value to change
    PreVal = Target.Value
End If

End Sub ```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate` will fire the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` function again but, it was the first thought I had too. I just edited in the `msgbox` when you commented too sorry. I was playing around with resizing the `Target` range to try and make it a bit more relevant to their selection than just defaulting to `A1` but I'm getting unexpected results when resizing to a single cell.

Comment: Yeah i've come to a similar conclusion. I can't seem to resize and unless we resize the user has the option of by passing the audit trail and simply deleting the data. the above isn't a perfect solution but by default to ```A1``` albeit the Macro he reactivates, it doesn't update the audit trail unless something is changed.

Comment: @Newbie `Set Target = Me.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))` will resize the range to the top left cell of the selection. i.e if cells `G17:H22` were selected, this would resize the `Target` range to `G17`. You could use this to then assign that cells value to your variable and inform the user via `MsgBox` "as more than 1 cell was selected, the cell that has been used is 'G17' " or something like that.

Comment: This works like a charm!! i have updated my previous ```A1``` selection to the following ```Set Target = Me.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))
Target.Select```

Comment: @Newbie FYI [I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402986/why-does-using-the-range-resize-property-not-output-the-expected-address-propert) about the unexpected results I was getting when testing resizing the `Target` property. The answer provides some useful info  along with a simpler way to do it in the comments.