# Why does using the Range.Resize property not output the expected Address property value?

Tags: excel, vba

I was answering another question and came across unexpected results when using `Range.Resize(1, 1)`.

I was looking to resize the `Target` property of the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` if a user selected more than 1 cell. Specifically I was intending to change the `Target` range to the top left cell of the selected range.

I noticed when testing this the resized `Target` range would not always result in the expected cell, often resulting in a column or row not within the original selection.

Testing code is as follows and;

- outputs to the immediate window with `<Target.Count> | <Target.Address>`
- Outputs to the immediate window the result of `Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False)`
- Assigns the result of `Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False)` to `Target`
- Outputs to the immediate window the new results of `<Target.Count> | <Target.Address>`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Debug.Print Target.Count & " | " & Target.Address(False, False)
   Debug.Print "Resize Address: " & Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False)
   Set Target = Target.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))
   Debug.Print Target.Count & " | " & Target.Address(False, False)
End Sub
```

> Side note: The cause of the issue is `Set Target = Target.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))` Specifically `Set Target = Target.Range...` should be `Set Target = Me.Range...` or just `Set Target = Range`.

Consider the following selections are made on the worksheet;

`Range("A1:C10)` and `Range(C1:E10")`

I expect the `Debug.Print` method of my test code to output:

```
30 | A1:C10
Resize Address: A1
1 | A1
30 | C1:E10
Resize Address: C1
1 | C1
```

The result I get is:

```
30 | A1:C10
Resize Address: A1
1 | A1
30 | C1:E10
Resize Address: C1
1 | E1    '<~~~~~
```

Although the address returned from the resize property is `C1` the range is set as `E1`
I've noticed it appears to set the new column to the right of the new target column the count of columns there are to the left of the new target column (i.e if I select `F1:F10` on the worksheet, it will resize to `K1`. `Column F` is 5 columns to the right of `Column A` and `Column K` is 5 columns to the right of `Column F`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Wouldn't this line `Target.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))` make it so you are taking a range relative to the target range, ie: C1 is 3 and 3 from C1 is E1

Comment: `Target.Cells(1,1)` will get you the top left cell of a range. So you can just do `Set Target = Target.Cells(1,1)`

Comment: @Warcupine I would expect `Debug.Print "Resize Address: " & Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False)` to output `E1` in that case, but it outputs `C1`.

Comment: No you are taking the range within a range in the C1 example. If you do the same with A1:E1 it will produce A1 because that is 1, so it won't offset the existing range.

Comment: When you do Target.Range(#) it doesn't start counting from the sheets A1, it starts counting from Targets top left. So Target.Range("C1") is not Sheet1.Range("C1") but rather, "C1" + TargetTopLeftCell

Comment: @Warcupine I'm understanding what you are saying, the why isn't clicking. I don't get why it's applying the offset.

Comment: @Toddleson That explains the why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
Target.Range(Target.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False))
```

is taking a range within an existing range. When that range starts at A1 `.resize(1, 1)` has an index of 1 so no offsetting of the original range.

When you start at C1 `.resize(1, 1)` now has an index of 3, the relative index of that range is C - 1, D - 2, E - 3. When you take the range of the range it offsets by 3 giving you E1.

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:E10")
    Debug.Print r.Address, r.Resize(1, 1).Address, "Normal Resize"
    Debug.Print r.Address, r.Range(r.Resize(1, 1).Address).Address, "Range offset resize"
    Set r = Range("C1:E10")
    Debug.Print r.Address, r.Resize(1, 1).Address, "Normal Resize"
    Debug.Print r.Address, r.Range(r.Resize(1, 1).Address).Address, "Range offset resize"
End Sub
```