# How to replicate the contents of a cell in one sheet to another sheet dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a database of homework questions that I use in my classroom. These are stored in a sheet call "Qu Data". I have a front sheet called "Dashboard". This sheet contains several dropdown menus to filter and search through topics. When I have selected a topic, I have used Index Match to pull through questions from the Qu Data sheet and displayed them on the Dashboard sheet.

The actual questions are in Word docs that are hyperlinked through the workbook. What appears on the Dashboard are question title, description, difficulty level etc. One of the columns is called "Used" and my plan is that this changes between Y and N depending on whether I have given students this question for homework this year or not.

As I will be viewing and selecting these question lists on the Dashboard sheet I will be changing the Y and N there.

My aim is to have this change replicated in the Qu Data sheet. This is so next time I use the dropdown menus on Dashboard and pull through a list of questions from the Qu Data sheet I can find out if I have used them before.

I tried doing it in VBA with this;

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Range("M20") Then
    If [M20] = "N" Then
        Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "N"
    ElseIf [M20] = "Y" Then
        Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "Y"
    End If
End If
```

This was my trial attempt as I will have a list of either 10, 20 or 25 questions for example on the Dashboard that have been index matched from the Qu Data sheet. I plan to change two or three Ns to Ys depending on what questions I select that time. These will then have to be reflected back to the Qu Data sheet so when they are pulled through again on a different day I know not to use them again.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was not far off.

I'll show you a way to get it working (as long as I understood your requirements) and after that I'll provide some explanation to the changes.

### Try changing the code to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Address(False, False) = "M20" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Target.Value = "N" Then
            Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "N"
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Y" Then
            Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "Y"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will

- Check if the `Target.Address` is (well, is not) `"M20"`
- If it's not `"M20"` the sub is exited, this prevents the code from executing unnecessarily for example, when it assigns `K8` with `"Y"` or `"N"`.
- The rest is unchanged in logic, though I prefer to avoid references like `[M20]` and like to use `Range("M20") instead.

Documentation:

- [Worksheet.Range Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range)
- [Range.Address Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)
- [Not Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/not-operator)

---

### Why didn't your version work as intended?

A couple of key things:

Per the [Range object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) documentation:

> *The default member of Range forwards calls without parameters to the Value property ...*

So that means

```
If Target.Range("M20") Then
```

is the same as

```
If Target.Range("M20").Value Then
```

I assume you intended for the code to be evaluating if the `Target` *is* `Range("M20")` and not the value of that range is `True` or `False`.

However, there is something else causing a deeper issue than that - [This answer on my question about unexpected results using Target.Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67403415/9663006) sheds some light on it.

If you were to create a new sheet and put `Debug.Print Target.Range("M20").Address` in the `Worksheet_Change()` event, you will see examples of what the above linked answer is talking about.

For example, If you change cell `M20` you would see `$Y$39` in the *immediate* window.

This is because the `Target.Address` is `$M$20` and we are then referencing another range with `$M$20` as the starting point - `$Y$39` is 12 Columns right of `M` (M is 12 columns right of A) and 20 rows down (including row 20 - the same offset as row 20 from row 1).

So that would mean with your version of the code, `If Target.Range("M20") Then` is checking the value of `Range("Y39")`. Unless the `Value` of `Y39` is `True`, your first `If Then` statement evaluates to `False` and thus *nothing happens*.

Comment: Hey. Thank you so much for taking the time to have a look at my problem. I am still struggling to get it working though. I copied your code into a vba module, saved it, changed M20 from Y to N, but nothing happened in cell K8 in the other sheet Qu Data. I am sure it's really close but I cant quite get there yet! Many thanks

Comment: The `If...Then` evaluation *is case sensitive*. Just to be clear are you putting *upper case* or *lower case* `Y/N` in `M20`?

Comment: Yes it is an upper case Y or N

Comment: @jon I guess this is why you shouldn't answer questions at middnight. I made the error I explained in my answer, please see the edited solution.

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant Sam. It works a treat now in that cell M20. Is there a way I could tweak it to extend to cells G19:G56 in Dashboard sheet so that each Y or N there corresponds to the respective cell in range K19:K56 in the Qu Data sheet. I have tried using the intersect function but cant get that to extend to these cells. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can construct your code to achieve what you want to do.

Here is another way to achieve your goal.

This solution;

- Allows handling of more than just Range `M20` in the `Worksheet_Change()` event.
- Checks for any specified range addresses (per whatever you add in) and executes another `Sub` to handle whatever checks and actions are required.

### Worksheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
    Case "M20"
        CheckCellM20 Target
    Case "C12"
        'Do some other routine if the change is in "C12"
    Case "A1"
        'Do some other routine if the change is in "A1"
    End Select
End Sub
```

### Any Worksheet or standard module in the same project:

```
Public Sub CheckCellM20(ByVal TargetCell As Range)
    If TargetCell.Value = "N" Then
        Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "N"
    ElseIf TargetCell.Value = "Y" Then
        Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "Y"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

So the `Worksheet_Change()` code will now evaluate per the `Select Case` statement whether the `Target.Address` matches one of the case strings. If it does it will then execute the code on the next line, in the case of `M20` it will execute the `Sub CheckCellM20` and pass the `Target` range via the `TargetCell` attribute. This allows for the same code as you would write in the `Worksheet_Change()` sub but to handle it elsewhere.

This method becomes useful when you have several cell changes you want to handle as it prevents excess clutter in the `Worksheet_Change()` event code and makes it much clearer what you are intending to handle and how (this is probably something you will thank yourself for in a year or two!).

Answer (score 0):

### To address your comment:

***Is there a way I could tweak it to extend to cells G19:G56 in Dashboard sheet so that each Y or N there corresponds to the respective cell in range K19:K56 in the Qu Data sheet.***

I have written the following for the `Worksheet_Change()` event which does the following;

- Declares two constants, the range address you want to check for changes in, and the worksheet name the values will correspond to.
- Loops through the `RangeToCheck` checking if each `Cell` address matches the `Target` address for the changed worksheet cell that triggered the event.
- Once matched it will update the corresponding row in column K on the `TargetWorksheet` *(by using the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset))*.

**Please Note:**

- This will only handle a single cell change at a time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const RangeToCheckAddress As String = "G19:G59"
    Const TargetWorksheetName As String = "Qu Data"
    Dim RangeToCheck As Range: Set RangeToCheck = Me.Range(RangeToCheckAddress)
    Dim CellToCheck As Range
    
    For Each CellToCheck In RangeToCheck
        If Target.Address = CellToCheck.Address Then
            If Target.Value = "Y" Or Target.Value = "N" Then
                Sheets(TargetWorksheetName).Range(CellToCheck.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value = Target.Value
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next CellToCheck
End Sub
```

---

### You could integrate this with the `M20` check like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const RangeToCheckAddress As String = "G19:G59"
    Const TargetWorksheetName As String = "Qu Data"
    Dim RangeToCheck As Range: Set RangeToCheck = Me.Range(RangeToCheckAddress)
    Dim CellToCheck As Range

    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
    Case "M20"
        CheckCellM20 Target
    Case Else
        For Each CellToCheck In RangeToCheck
            If Target.Address = CellToCheck.Address Then
                If Target.Value = "Y" Or Target.Value = "N" Then
                    Sheets(TargetWorksheetName).Range(CellToCheck.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value = Target.Value
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next CellToCheck
    End Select
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub CheckCellM20(ByVal TargetCell As Range)
    If TargetCell.Value = "N" Then
        Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "N"
    ElseIf TargetCell.Value = "Y" Then
        Sheets("Qu Data").Range("K8") = "Y"
    End If
End Sub
```